# Using SDF's Horizon server for Production Systems

Tags: horizon

I know SDF provides a public Horizon server too. My question from those who are using for their  production apps, is it reliable enough or would you suggest running your own Horizon server?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Could you expand this?

Comment: no sudden death reported since its early release, so you may consider it reliable w.r.t. OS level. For other aspects, please expand on what you want to know precisely...

Comment: @cesarm my question was basically about system down/network down perspective. What is uptime guarantee?

Comment: For uptime guarantee, you may Supervisor (or other daemons) to make the process restarts itself when it is detected down. Even when your host machine is down, Supervisor will help you auto-bootup the services, and then Stellar Core will automatically start its catchup process. From my experience of almost 2 years, the process never went down itself on my nodes (unless the host machine was occassionally resetted or had its power cut).

Comment: @cesarm I was talking about Horizon Server uptime. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Horizon is the same - I maintain it via Supervisor, also no down for over a year.

Answer (score 1):

The public Horizon instance that SDF runs isn't meant to be used beyond an easy way to try out the Stellar network. If you're intending to build some kind of product on Stellar, it's expected that you run your own instance of Horizon. For toy projects or for initial validation of an idea, SDF's public Horizon is quite stable, but provides no uptime guarantees.

The main reason for this is to avoid centralization. If the ecosystem of projects built on Stellar all communicate with a single Horizon instance, that's a significant single point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty reliable, they seem to have a good high availability setup and a strong interest in providing a stable service. But I don't think you will get an uptime guarantee or SLA for any free service, so this is not not necessarily an option if you run a serious business. If reliability is critical for you, you'll more likely want to operate your own stellar cluster.

The main downside of the public SDF horizon is its rate limit that kicks in when you run over 100 (not sure, someone correct me if I'm wrong) requests per minute per IP.